Infinite sum related to Hurwitz Zeta
I want to evaluate the following sum:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+a)^2}
\end{equation}
Where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is not an integer. Such is similar to $\zeta(2,a)$, but it ranges over the entire line and it's alternating. I know you can just note that this is minus the residue of $f(z)=\pi\csc\pi z$ at $z = −a$, such that:
\begin{equation}
\pi \frac{d}{dz} \csc(\pi z) \bigg|_{z = -a} = -\frac{\pi^2 \cos(-\pi a)}{\sin^2(-\pi a)}=-S
\end{equation}
Yielding the result. That's fine and all, but I've been wanting a different approach. I've tried using the weierstrass factorization for trig functions, but got nowhere. Also tried Poisson's summation formula, but got nowhere also.
Any help is appreciated.

You can consider the sum $f(t)= \sum_n e^{i(n+a)t}/(n+a) ^2$ for which you are interested in $f(\pi)$, and twice take a derivative by $t$

Cross-posted from Math StackExchange.

Here is a derivation using the Fourier series of $\cos ax$:
$$\cos ax=\frac{\sin \pi a}{\pi a}+\frac{2a\sin\pi a}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cos nx}{a^2-n^2}.$$
Hence for $x=0$ we have the identity
$$\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi a}=\frac{1}{a}+2a\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{a^2-n^2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{a+n}.$$
Take the derivative with respect to $a$ and the desired result follows,
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(a+n)^2}=\frac{\pi^2 \cos\pi a}{\sin^2 \pi a}.$$
